# Eigenvalues of (restrictions of) the standard representation of $S_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, determinant

Let the permutation group on $n$ elements $S_n$ act on a set $S$ of size $k < n$ via permutations. Fix some ordering on the elements of $S$ to make this sensible.

- Is there any way to understand the eigenvalues of the $k \times k$ matrices thus obtained?
- Anything special happens to the answer of the above question if one looks at a subgroup $H < G$ which permutes these $k$ elements? Like anything can be said about the representation of $H$ thus obtained?

Comment: There are very few such actions of $S_{n}.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Can you kindly elaborate? Say $k=3$ and $n=5$. Then there are many elements ($3! \times 2! = 12$) of $S_5$ which will move between some fixed $3$ elements.

Comment: If $S_{n}$ acts as a group of permutations of a set of size $k<n$ then this implies the existence of a homomorphism from $S_{n}$ to $S_{k}.$ There is such a homomorphism for $k =2$ for any $n,$ but other than this, there is no such non-trivial homomorphism when $n >4.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I am not doing something that strong. I am saying that you restrict to some subgroup of $S_n$ which permutes this set of $k <n$ elements. Like say you could always find a copy of $S_3$ in some $S_{n>3}$. I am asking about how the eigenvalues of this action can be understood for this copy of $S_3$ chosen inside $S_{n>3}$.

Comment: Then I think you need too clarify what your first sentence is intended to mean.